# Passing values from Python to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, html

For a research project we are developing a system in python which takes raw data from a real time sensor and applies different DSP filters to it. So far so good. The other part of the system should be the plotting of the data and the access to some controllers for modifying the sample rate and other parameters. The last days I have been trying to use HTML5 + javascript as the technology to do the data plotting; I am using d3.js for the graphics and mimic.js to implement the xmlrpc protocol to communicate the python side with the HTML file. After a lot of tweaking i ALMOST managed to communicate both parts of the system. However, I ran into the 'Cross origin request' error (I am using chrome).

After that I have been thinking of some other strategies in order to communicate python with the GUI:

1. Using a SimpleHTTPServer. However, I need to have a SimpleXMLRPCServer running so I can register the function (register_function) to pass the value. Is there a way to implement a xmlrpc within a SimpleHTTPServer?
2. I have been thinking about using json but I am not sure if this is the best way to go as the data streaming will be quite big  and fast(4 channels with constant updates).

So after all this testing I really would appreciate a piece of advice:

1. Is if feasible to have such HTML5 GUI? is it efficient for plotting such amounts of data?
2. if so, what would be a realistic strategy to implement a communication between Python and HTML/js?
3. Is xmlrpc the best protocol to use?

Comment: Any reason you're not using matplotlib (http://matplotlib.org/)? Are you in need of a more complex gui than that?

Comment: You want to send JSON between Python and JavaScript

Comment: If your application is running locally (i.e. the cause of that cross origin requests error is that you are loading stuff from `file://` or `C:/`) there is no need for a HTML/web interface, so you may use some desktop toolkit such as PyQT to build your GUI, and exploit an advanced plotting library such as the already cited matoptlib from there.

Comment: I already have a GUI running with pyQT but we are thinking of implementing something that can be portable so the GUI can be used both on the computer that hosts the sensor and on embedded devices

Comment: @Mr E: i am using xmlrpc because it is very light: i am taking plotting data in very short time periods. Is still JSON a good option keeping that in mind?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yep. Also you can use some JavaScript charts libraries. Such as [amCharts](http://amcharts.com), [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), [plot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/).
2. Really, JSON is better.
3. XMLRPC isn't very light. See p.2 :)